# latex Encode the image below using run length encoding

Tags: texlive

This question concerns run length encoding. This is a way of reducing the ﬁle size of an image without losing any information (lossless compression). Run length encoding relies on statistical correlations of pixel values, for example long runs of pixels of the same colour. We’ll start with a simple example, shown below:
We could list the pixel values (with white as 1 and black as 0) starting at the top left and going along each row one at a time as follows:
11111100111111000111110...100111111
It is clear that there are long strings of both white and black pixels. In this case, it would be more eﬃcient to store the number of pixels in each string. Using the convention that

[image]
we always start with a string of white pixels, the image could be written as
6,2,6,3,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,2,6. Since the largest number we need to store is 6, and 22 −1 = 3 < 6 ≤ 7 = 23 −1, we require, for a ﬁxed bit length for each value, 3 bits per number. Since there are 13 strings of pixels, we require 13×3 = 39 bits in total. This compares well with the storage space for the image stored directly with one bit per pixel (black or white), requiring 54 bits (as there are 54 pixels).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the question?

Comment: I want to how should I type into Latex that can output the command as a graph as above.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newif\ifwhite
\newcommand\zz[1]{%
\begin{flushleft}
\hsize=\dimexpr9em+18\fboxsep+18\fboxrule\relax
\whitetrue
\@for\z:=#1\do{%
  \loop
   \fbox{\ifwhite\phantom{\rule{1em}{1em}}\else\rule{1em}{1em}\fi}%
   \linebreak[0]%
   \edef\z{\the\numexpr\z-1\relax}%
   \ifnum\z>0
   \repeat
   \ifwhite\whitefalse\else\whitetrue\fi
}%
\end{flushleft}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\zz{6,2,6,3,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,2,6}

\end{document}
```